# Bootstrap and IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble using Bootstrap and IE8: some pages are displayed well, but others break.

The error is:

> Invalid procedure call or argument respond.js line 211 Character 7

In that line in the javascript, this appears:

```
if (ss.styleSheet) {
ss.styleSheet.cssText = css; 
}
```

The code that adds all pages is this:

```
<- [if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="/Style%20Library/Styles/js/html5shiv.js"> </ script> 
<script src="/Style%20Library/Styles/js/respond.js"> </ script> 
<! [endif] ->
```

What I mean is that the columns lose their correct widths and take 100% of the width of the page.

What's causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to too many stylesheets in IE8:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/202